# Trying to change color on Tabs in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-tabhost

Below is my Tab class. I am trying to change the color of the tabs, when selected and unselected. But the app crashes when I call **tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(MyOnTabChangeListener)**?. I can't even start the app with that method and it gives a nullpointerexception. I am not sure what to do? Any Ideas? /Regards

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Tabs extends TabActivity
{
private static final String TAG = "TabHostActivity";
private boolean mHaveShownStartDialog = false;
static TabHost tabHost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_host);
    setOnCreatePreferences();

    try
    {

        addTab(getString(R.string.Search), R.drawable.searchtab, SearchTask.class );
        addTab(getString(R.string.Bookmarks), R.drawable.blackheart1, Bookmarks.class );
        addTab(getString(R.string.Latest), R.drawable.clock3, Latest.class );
        addTab(getString(R.string.QAndA), R.drawable.pen, LatestFeedback.class );

        getTabHost().setCurrentTab( 0 );
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(MyOnTabChangeListener);


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }


}

public static OnTabChangeListener MyOnTabChangeListener = new OnTabChangeListener(){

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
      for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
      {
          tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
      }

      tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
};





//public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
//    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
//    {
//        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); //unselected
 //   }
 //   tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")); // selected
//}


private void addTab( CharSequence label, int drawable_id, Class<?> c ) 
{
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("tab" + " "+ label);

    spec.setIndicator( label, getResources().getDrawable( drawable_id ) );

    spec.setContent( new Intent().setClass( this, c ) );

    getTabHost().addTab( spec );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate( R.menu.tabs_menu, menu );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch ( item.getItemId() ) 
    {
        case R.id.tabs_menu_options_item:
            //startActivityForResult( new Intent( this, Options.class ) , 0 ); 
            return true;

        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void setOnCreatePreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getBaseContext() );

    boolean mUseStartDialog = preferences.getBoolean( "use_dialog", true );
    if( mUseStartDialog ) 
    {
        if( !mHaveShownStartDialog )
        {
            mHaveShownStartDialog = true;
            startActivity( new Intent( this, WelcomeDialog.class ) );
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see where you initialize tabHost variable.

Comment: (Ha! Good catch.) This is correct, a NullPointerException is caused by trying to call `null.setOnTabChangedListener()`.

Comment: Cheers, that was a realy stupid miss. I now call getTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(). Sometimes you get blind to your own code ;). Now I can start the app, but when I try to change tab i get a new nullpointerexception and it crashes on row: **for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)**. I can't put getTabHost().getTabWidget() here, what shall I do ?

Comment: Please update your question code for when and how you initialize tabhost variable.

Also I wouldn't go for the TabActivity in the first place. It lacks fragment support needed for tablet screens. Use rather tabhost as a separate widget instead. Here you can find very easy and readable example code how it should be done [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that through OnTabChangeListener. You DON'T want to call the code every time user presses the tab ;) You can write it directly after

```
getTabHost().setCurrentTab( 0 );
```

This is the code I use for this scenario:

```
TabWidget widget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
int size = widget.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    // Hail to the master of unreadable code!
    ((TextView)((ViewGroup)widget.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setTextColor(0xffffffff);
    widget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_widget_background_selector);
}
```

What I am suggesting here is that you should use a selector and let platform handle everything for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_widget_background_selected"/>
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/tab_widget_background_casual"/>
  </selector>
```